# Sign out REST API Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, integration

Is there is a built in REST API for `sign out` in Magento because I looked in the reference and couldn't find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, my Magento version is 2.1.5, I cannot find the API for the "sign out" function. However, seem that Magento builds the revoked token by customer id method already.

*vendor/magento/module-integration/Api/CustomerTokenServiceInterface.php*

[*vendor/magento/module-integration/Model/CustomerTokenService.php::revokeCustomerAccessToken()*](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Integration/Model/CustomerTokenService.php#L93)

**[NOT TEST MY CODE]**

app/code/Vendor/Integration/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/integration/customer/revoke" method="POST">
        <service class="Vendor\Integration\Api\CustomerRevokeTokenServiceInterface"
                 method="revokeCustomerAccessToken"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

app/code/Vendor/Integration/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\Integration\Api\CustomerRevokeTokenServiceInterface"
                type="Vendor\Integration\Model\CustomerRevokeTokenService" />
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Integration/Api/CustomerRevokeTokenServiceInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Integration\Api;
/**
 * Interface CustomerRevokeTokenServiceInterface
 * @package Vendor\Integration\Api
 */
interface  CustomerRevokeTokenServiceInterface 
{
    /**
     * Revoke token by customer id.
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function revokeCustomerAccessToken($customerId);
}
```

app/code/Vendor/Integration/Model/CustomerRevokeTokenService.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Integration\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Integration\Model\CredentialsValidator;
use Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\Token as Token;
use Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory as TokenModelFactory;
use Magento\Integration\Model\ResourceModel\Oauth\Token\CollectionFactory as TokenCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\Token\RequestThrottler;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;

class CustomerRevokeTokenService
    implements \Vendor\Integration\Api\CustomerRevokeTokenServiceInterface
{
    /**
     * Token Model
     *
     * @var TokenModelFactory
     */
    private $tokenModelFactory;

    /**
     * Customer Account Service
     *
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    private $accountManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Integration\Model\CredentialsValidator
     */
    private $validatorHelper;

    /**
     * Token Collection Factory
     *
     * @var TokenCollectionFactory
     */
    private $tokenModelCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var RequestThrottler
     */
    private $requestThrottler;

    /**
     * Initialize service
     *
     * @param TokenModelFactory $tokenModelFactory
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
     * @param TokenCollectionFactory $tokenModelCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Integration\Model\CredentialsValidator $validatorHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        TokenModelFactory $tokenModelFactory,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        TokenCollectionFactory $tokenModelCollectionFactory,
        CredentialsValidator $validatorHelper
    ) {
        $this->tokenModelFactory = $tokenModelFactory;
        $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
        $this->tokenModelCollectionFactory = $tokenModelCollectionFactory;
        $this->validatorHelper = $validatorHelper;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function revokeCustomerAccessToken($customerId)
    {
        $tokenCollection = $this->tokenModelCollectionFactory->create()->addFilterByCustomerId($customerId);
        if ($tokenCollection->getSize() == 0) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('This customer has no tokens.'));
        }
        try {
            foreach ($tokenCollection as $token) {
                $token->setRevoked(1)->save();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('The tokens could not be revoked.'));
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Remember to create `registration.php` and `module.xml` files.

We can use the revoke customer access token: `/V1/integration/customer/revoke`

Comment: Thanks Khoa, but how can I use it as an API for my mobile application.

Comment: You should create a custom API on the Magento side. Re-use this method. On the mobile application side, we can call the custom api.

Comment: You should know how to create a custom api first: http://inchoo.net/magento/api-magento/magento-2-custom-api/

Comment: @Jsparo30 Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I tried and got the error {"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"customerId"}. I used method POST and my API is https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/revoke  and the header parameter is Authorization   Bearer 1mt6w4xku39ano7p7nqgjmalbd5fvoew

Comment: Seem that you missed to pass the customerId param.

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Vendor\Integration\Api\CustomerRevokeTokenServiceInterface in /var/www/domain.com/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:93

Comment: See my updated code and read more here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2502

Answer (score 0):

Since you use token authentication, simply delete the token from your client.

Revoking the token would only be useful if you want to force a log out from the server side, like if you changed the password.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a build in REST API to sign out of Magento.

```
POST /rest/default/V1/integration/customer/revoke-customer-token
```

without any parameter, but set the token as bearer token, and it will revoke the token.

**Example:**

#1 Sign in using the following API

```
POST /rest/V1/integration/customer/token
{"username":"customer_email@xyz.com", "password":"Abc_123"}
```

#2 Get the customer information using this API and setting #1 Sign in API response as bearer token

```
GET /rest/V1/customers/me/
```

#3 Then call this API to revoke customer token or sign out. (setting #1 Sign in API response as bearer token)

```
POST /rest/V1/integration/customer/revoke-customer-token
```

Now again call #2 Get Customer Information API and you won't be able to do so, because token is revoked.

Look for these and more APIs documentation in ReDocly: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/